# Disk Utility frozen when running in recovery mode

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, macos, performance

I'm on macOS Sierra and earlier today I ran disk utility and it told me that there was something wrong with the disk (it said something about exit code 8) and I should boot into Recovery mode and run disk utility there. So I rebooted into Recovery mode and started running disk utility.

Right now Disk utility has been running for 2 hours, and it's been stuck at "Checking catalog hierarchy". The mouse is frozen, and the laptop doesn't respond to any keyboard events (like changing screen brightness).

Is it frozen because it just has a lot of work todo? (I have a 500GB disk). Does this process take a very long time? Should I force reboot and try something else?

Comment: Is it a Hard disc or a SSD

Comment: It is a Macbook Pro SSD. The Macbook pro is one of the newer generation ones.

Comment: Is it your main drive or a second partition ?, do you have a Time Machine backup?

Comment: It is my main drive & partition. I have a time machine backup but its 6 months old, so I'd really like to recover this partition if I can.

Comment: You can maybe try to shutdown your computer (hold power for 10 sec) and hope your drive won't be corrupted?

Comment: That's my last move @Harcker I'm assuming the disk check shouldn't take this long? Going on for 3 hours now

Comment: It's patience vs value of data. Give it a day, just in case.